# Foundation.framework icon red, and the path is incorrect for Cocoapod due to Xcode 8 Beta. I know the proper path, but can't set it

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, cocoapods

The path for Foundation.framework is pointing to:

`/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework`

It does not exist. The only thing I need to change is `/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/` to `/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/`, but when I click on the "change path" from Xcode, I cannot get access to the Xcode-beta.app by right clicking and doing show package contents. I couldn't find a way to do it programmatically within any of my files either, how could I fix this?

This is for the firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have any red files related to 3rd party dependencies instead of checking paths in Build Phases and Build Settings etc I often delete all pods folders and podconfig files and run `pod install` again from the Terminal. Then I clean and Build and usually all is good. It's much quicker and will likely fix other problems you aren't aware of yet because there could be pod updates you've missed as well.